# What is the fastest way to remove duplicates from tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mysql-8.0

The way I am currently doing it is by storing the unique records in another table first

```
insert into stagging_table(col1,col2...) select distinct col1, col2 from target_table
```

and then truncate target_table and then copy data back into target_table from stagging_table

```
insert into target_table(col1,col2...) select col1, col2 from stagging_table
```

However this process is time consuming for tables with over 55 gb of data. Can anyone suggest any easier way to achieve this?

Comment: In the step two drop `target_table` and then rename  `stagging_table` to `target_table`

Comment: @ErgestBasha The problem is the first step itself is taking a long time. Should I try adding indexes in the target table?

Comment: Adding indexes in the target table will more likely slow down the storing as indexes also have to be maintained

Comment: [Multiple options and suggestions and tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql+drop+duplicates&t=newext&atb=v362-1&ia=web)

Comment: Without conditions you are forced to run the entire table. You can try another method without using distinct ``INSERT INTO stagging_table  WITH uniques_records AS ( select *, row_number()over(partition by col1,col2,.. order by some column asc/desc) as row_num ) SELECT col1,col2,...  FROM uniques_records WHERE row_num = 1; ``

Comment: *The problem is the first step itself is taking a long time.* Define `stagging_table (col1,col2)` as PRIMARY KEY then use `insert IGNORE into stagging_table(col1,col2) select col1, col2 from target_table;`.

Comment: *tables with over 55 gb of data* - What is unique data size?

Comment: You could try SELECT INTO OUTFILE, followed by LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. These operations are usually pretty fast.